# two custom post type sharing same category

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to add same category for multiple custom post type?

for example,

coupon post type -
deal post type -
both should share common cateogires, such as health, travel etc.

But, when we create new post type, looks like, we need to provide custom category also.

Do you have any clue how to create custom post types without custom categories?

Comment: you should look at accepting some of the previous q's you have posted. as for this register_taxonomy()

Comment: My bad, sorry, I did not know that i can accept the answer.  thanks to point me, I have accepted the answer for all my questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, custom-post-types can have multiple taxonomies ( categories, tags, custom ).

Yes, you can have a custom post type without a taxonomy.

Adding categories to custom post types is done like so:

```
'taxonomies'          => [ 'category' ], // <--- add this (or use 'post_tag' to add tags to the CPT)
'public'              => true,
'show_ui'             => true,
'exclude_from_search' => true,
'hierarchical'        => true,
'supports'            => [
    'title', 
    'editor', 
    'thumbnail',
],
'query_var'           => true,
```

If you want to add a custom taxonomy to multiple post types, you can do this:

```
function people_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'people', [ // <-- 'people' taxo added to posts, pages, & custom_post_type
            'post', 
            'page', 
            'custom_post_type',
        ],
        array(
            'label'        => __( 'People' ),
            'rewrite'      => [
                'slug'     => 'person',
            ],
            'capabilities' => [
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
                'edit_terms'   => 'publish_guides',
            ]
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'people_init' );
```